# What qiskit version?

Tags: programming, qiskit

How do I find out what version of qiskit I am running?

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open because there's already 3 excellent answers and I couldn't find any similar question to mark it as a "duplicate". Voting "needs details for clarity" seems like an abuse of the system, because the question does not really need more details or clarity.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the command:

```
qiskit.__qiskit_version__
```

Current qiskit version is 0.23.4 as you can see below:

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.16.3',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.7.3',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.5.1',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.11.1',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.8.1',
 'qiskit': '0.23.4'}
```

If you want to see the changes in different versions then you can check the [Release Note](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html) posted by the IBM team when there is an update to the system.

Comment: In the windows powershell I tried qiskit.__qiskit_version__ on every level of directory from c: through c:\users\lewis\qiskit-terra\qiskit. Every time I get:

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code you need to run to know which version you have:

```
import qiskit.tools.jupyter
%qiskit_version_table
%qiskit_copyright
```

If you want to check the latest version, you can go read the [release notes](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html) :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the **qiskit_version** command only works inside of a python virtual env with qiskit installed.

So, I recommended to install qiskit inside of a Python virtual environment for better experience and performance as suggested [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html) and that should help with your question too.

Once a Python virtual environment is created using conda (Anaconda), install qiskit using pip install qiskit. Then import qiskit into your virtual environment and run **qiskit_version**

open the directory in which you want to work in the terminal and then...

```
conda create -n qiskit_virtualenv python=3.8

conda activate qiskit_virtualenv

pip install qiskit

import qiskit

__qiskit_version__
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed qiskit using pip, you could run the following on the command line:

```
pip show qiskit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip list | grep "qiskit"
pip list | grep "IBMQuantumExperience"
pip list | grep "qiskit-aer"
pip list | grep "qiskit-terra"
python --version
```

In notebook add "!" at the begining