# Is it possible to automatically rename a job at submission time?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I would like to find out if there is some way to rename a job automatically, either when the job is first sent to the queue, or later after the fact. I've tried searching through the forum and the documentation to try and find a solution, but nothing that seems to do the trick. The closest I have found is the `qobj_id` parameter, however, this is depreciated and no longer functions.

Edit: I finally found a (frustratingly easy) solution, see my answer below

Comment: I think the answer is a straight no. IDs are meant to be fixed and meaningful to the server. I suggest to save your job IDs in some csv file.

Comment: @DanieleCuomo The job name is different from the job ID. if you go into the job details you can manually rename the job, which is an identifier separate from the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution. It actually ended up being so simple, that I think the only way that I had missed it was that I was looking for a solution within `backend.run()` or `execute()` and not the job object itself. The solution uses the `job.update_name()` method and here is a simple implementation of it.

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_nairobi')

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(1, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])

job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=8192, memory=True)
job.update_name('test_name') #the new job will have the name "test_name"
```

Comment: Which version of qiskit have you used?

Comment: @MicheleAmoretti I'm honestly not sure. I work through IBM's Quantum Lab notebooks, so I suppose I use which ever version that defaults to. This was the documentation page that eventually lead me to the solution, if this helps tell what version I might be using: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.html

Comment: I found the same documentation but I did not post it because it is no longer valid on the latest qiskit release.

Comment: @MicheleAmoretti After doing some ready, I do agree that it is not the latest version of qiskit. However, considering that is still supported by the quantum computer side of IBM's service (as evidenced by the fact that I can actively run jobs like this), this solution should be considered valid.

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15741/what-qiskit-version

Answer (score 3):

Recently, the API for submitting jobs has changed. I suggest you to read the following documents:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-provider

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-provider/blob/main/docs/tutorials/Migration_Guide_from_qiskit-ibmq-provider.ipynb

As you can read there, job name is no longer supported.

Comment: I'm not sure if job name is completely unsupported. I actually managed to find a solution for this, see the answer that I posted.